# How to find maximum acceptable deflection?

Tags: beam

I have a beam. I have its Young's modulus. I don't have its maximum acceptable deflection. How can I determine the maximum acceptable deflection without breaking the beam?

Comment: Define "acceptable". For example if the floor in your house flexes two inches up and down when you walk across the room, but there is no danger of anything breaking, is that "acceptable"?  On the other hand, for a steel spring in a machine it might be "unacceptable" if you can only coil it into 20 complete turns around an axle, if 30 turns is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yield strength of steels is generally defined by 0.2% deflection . So if you do not exceed 0.2% strain under load you will not permanently deform it .The specification of the steel will give the minimum Yield Strength. Then if your load does not cause a stress greater than this specified yield strength it will not "break".

Comment: Yield strength is exactly the term that I was looking for.